# LaTeX reference came out as "&" instead of as "and"

Tags: apa-style

LaTeX reference came out as `&` instead of `and`. I tried to to modify the `apa.bst` file but when I search for `&` or `/&` `\&`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Do please tell us which citation-related packages you employ  (if any) and which bibliography style you use.

Comment: APA style requires use of `&` instead of `and` in certain situations, so if you ordered an APA bibliography and citations this is expected and desired. In any case we need to know more about your document to be able to help. There are several packages out there that implement APA style, some like `apacite` and `biblatex-apa` try to follow the APA guidelines as closely as possible, others like `apalike.bst` are only 'like APA'. If we don't know what you use, we can't give any useful advice.

Comment: The `apa.bst` is ancient, and should probably not be used anyway. But without any code to see what you're doing it's impossible to tell.

Comment: hi, thanks for the replies. I use apacite package for references and I took references from mendeley reference manager program.

Comment: I want references in the form (A and B) instead of (A&B). @HenriMenke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apacite` package provides quite a bit of flexibility in modifying certain parts of the formatting, so it would be useful to read its [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/apacite).

The format of the 'and' between names in parenthetical citations is controlled by the `\BBAA` macro. If you redefine this at the beginning of the document you can replace the `&` with `and`.

For future questions, *please* give a minimal document showing exactly what you're doing so that people don't have to guess or ask multiple questions in comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{ex88,
    Author = {Borman, W. C. and Hanson, M. A. and Oppler, S. H. and Pulakos, E. D. and White, L. A.},
    Journal = {Journal of Applied Psychology},
    Pages = {443--449},
    Title = {Role of Early Supervisory Experience in Supervisor Performance},
    Volume = {78},
    Year = {1993}}

@article{4.05-2,
    Author = {Bretschneider, J. G. and McCoy, N. L.},
    Journal = {Archives of Sexual Behavior},
    Pages = {343--350},
    Title = {Sexual Interest and Behavior in Healthy 80- to 102-Year-Olds},
    Volume = {14},
    Year = {1968}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}}
\begin{document}

\citep{ex88, 4.05-2}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked perfectly.. A follow up question what is the code for et al. I would like to change it to my preferred language.

Comment: You can add `\renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{et al.}` and change it to whatever you need (also inside the `\AtBeginDocument` command.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help. Saved my days.